# Upload images to different folders in s3 (by album names) using Shrine gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-5, shrine

I managed to upload files to s3 using shrine, but I'm trying to upload each photo to a different folder according to the album it belongs to.

Lets say i have a bucket named: `abc`:

Uploading images to the album: `family` should upload images to: `abc/family/...`

Uploading images to the album: `friends` should upload images to: `abc/friends/...`

I didn't find a way to do it in `Shrine.storages` in the initializer file.

I guess the way to do it is with `default_storage` and `dynamic_storage` plugins somehow, but i didn't succeed doing it yet.

any suggestions / solution?

Thanks a lot :)

Relations:

`Album has_many :photos
Photo belongs_to :album`

`Photo` class has `image_data` field for Shrine.

my code in the initializer: (basic stuff)

```
s3_options = {
  access_key_id:     ENV["S3_KEY"],
  secret_access_key: ENV["S3_SECRET"],
  region:            ENV["S3_REGION"],
  bucket:            ENV["S3_BUCKET"],
}

Shrine.storages = {
  cache: Shrine::Storage::S3.new(prefix: "cache", **s3_options),
  store: Shrine::Storage::S3.new(prefix: "store", **s3_options),
}
```

EDIT:

I found out there is a plugin named: `pretty_location` which adds a nicer folder structure, but its not exactly what i need, it adds `/Photo/:photo_id/image/:image_name` under the bucket, but i need the album name instead.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I did it!

by overriding `generate_location` in the `ImageUploader` file:

```
class ImageUploader < Shrine
  def generate_location(io, context = {})
    album_name  = context[:record].album_name if context[:record].album
    name  = super # the default unique identifier

    [album_name, name].compact.join("/")
  end
end
```

this will upload the files to: `:bucket_name/storage/:album_name/:file_name`

If you want other folder then "`storage`" you need to change the `prefix` under the `Shrine.storages` in the initializer file.

You might want to use `parameterize` on the `field_name` (in my case `album_name.parameterize`) so you wont have spaces and unwanted characters in the path.

For anyone out there looking for the answer! thats what worked for me, Enjoy.

If you have other working/better solution, please post it as well.
thanks.

Comment: This is not working if I use `Tus Server` with `Shrine`. Tus may be overriding Shrine configs. Any idea how we can do this using Tus Server?

Comment: For this to work we must use `ImageUploader.upload` method or just using `photo.save`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with even more customization reading from a JSON file

```
{"ID":"14","post_author":"2","guid":"wp-content\/uploads\/2012\/02\/Be-True-Website-Logo3.png","post_type":"attachment","post_parent":"13"}
```

This allows you to get the location of the guid by running a each loop like this

```
require 'json'
require 'pry'

file = File.read('files.json')
array = JSON.parse(file)
posts = array[2]["data"] #please change this to match your JSON file

posts.each do |post|
  post_id = post['post_parent']
  if Post.find_by_id(post_id)
    p = Post.find(post_id)
    g = Graphic.new(post_id: post_id)
    g.graphic = File.open(post["guid"])
  else
    g = Graphic.new
    g.graphic = File.open(post["guid"])
  end
  g.save
end
```

You can run the above file in rails console as well..

Below is what your Uploader should look like...

```
class GraphicUploader < Shrine
  include ImageProcessing::MiniMagick
  plugin :activerecord
  plugin :cached_attachment_data # for retaining the cached file across form redisplays
  plugin :restore_cached_data # re-extract metadata when attaching a cached file
  plugin :determine_mime_type
  plugin :remove_attachment

  def generate_location(io, context = {})
    name  = super # the default unique identifier

    if io.is_a?(File)
      initial_location  = io.to_path
      new_location      = initial_location.match(/(.*\/).*/)[1]
      final_location = [new_location + name].compact.join # returns original path
    else
      foo = [io.id].compact.join.to_s
    end

    end
  end
end
```